# How to upload images to GitHub without gimmicks (on a Mac)?

Tags: git, github

https://github.com/rdpeng/ExData_Plotting1/tree/master/figure

Above you can see someone uploading images to Github without using gimmicks like "Issues" or "Wiki". My "desktop" version of Github has issues and I don't think it has an option to upload images. Since the "desktop" version won't work in command prompt either - is there a "normal" way to upload images to Github?

P.S: Is there a reason why this is so complicated? I can see questions on Stackoverflow and blog posts about this (none of which solves the problem) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a "normal" way to upload images to Github?

The "normal" way to do it is to add the images to your local copy of the repository and then use `git` to commit your changes and push them to the remote repo, which is Github. So it's be something like:

```
$ git add myImage.png
$ git commit -m "Adding myImage.png"
$ git push origin
```

> Is there a reason why this is so complicated?

It's really *not* complicated unless you don't know how to use `git` or at least have some experience with other version control systems. `git` and Github began as (and largely remain) tools that programmers use to share source code files, and your `R` files qualify as source code.

It *is* complicated, though, if you're looking at Github as some kind of web hosting service. You have to realize that a `git` repository tracks all the changes you make to the files it contains -- it's a lot more than just a directory with files. There are quite a few basic guides to `git` and Github, and reading [one of those](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/01/14/non-programmer-git-intro/) would be a good way to start shifting your perspective. It looks like you're taking *Exploratory Data Analysis* with Roger Peng, perhaps through Coursera? You'll use Github to share all your assignments in that class, so getting comfortable with `git` now will pay dividends for the rest of the class.

> My "desktop" version of Github has issues and I don't think it has an option to upload images.

Again, it sounds like you mostly need to change your perspective. Your installation of "Github Desktop" may indeed have issues, although it's usually a pretty straightforward installation. Github and `git` don't much care whether a file is a .R file, an image, your weekly shopping list, or any other file. If you've: 1) created a repository on Github; and then 2) cloned that repo to your local machine; then you should have a local directory on your machine that's a copy of what's in your Github repo. You can create files in that directory or copy them there, and then use `git add` to add them to the list of files that `git` tracks. Use `git commit` to create "a commit" which contains all your changes since the previous commit. Use `git push` to copy your commits, and thus all your changes, from your local copy of the repo to the one on Github. You can do some of these steps through Github Desktop if you like, but in order to understand what to do in Github Desktop it helps to have a handle on the underlying `git` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can now drag and drop an image file on wiki page in edit mode.
https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-14-upload-images-to-wiki-pages

Hacks like uploading an image to a github issue are no longer required.

Start by editing your wiki page.  Then drop an image file into the browser window.  The file gets uploaded, a link to the uploaded file is created and added to your wiki text like this in markdown:

```
 ![load-test-in-a-box architecture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/175773/204170426-54f26911-f35b-49db-9dcb-8f6183dfe8c9.jpg)
```

Here is the actual image:

[image: load-test-in-a-box architecture]